# Can we convert timezone text into UTC offset number in Power Query?

Tags: powerbi, timezone, powerquery

My data has two columns:

Datetime from different timezones
Timezones in text format

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0N22.png)

In order to convert those time to my local time, I first need to get the UTC offset numbers based on the "timezone text" column. Does Power query have any functions that can handle that straightforward?

I have tried to search in the Power Query library but cannot find anything that does the job.

Comment: I believe you will have to make your own conversion table and merge it

Comment: A Google search for some of those abbreviations gives me this spreadsheet: [Time Zones in AIRS](https://ibc.doi.gov/sites/default/files/AQD/aviation/time-zones-in-airs.xlsx) - though your screenshot appears to show slightly different variations (ex. "CST_NA").  Is this the data set you're using?  If not, please let us know where the data comes from, as the screenshot alone is not enough to identify the table of valid time zone identifiers for your system.

Comment: Yes, I have tables of timezones and timezone rules where I can convert manually. But it is a lot of manual work. That was what I did 4 years ago. Now I have to repeat the same task and was hoping that Power Query could have made some simple function in the mean time to enable this job in a more straight forward way ... But it seems that I was too optimistic.

Comment: It has nothing to do with PowerQuery.  Your list of time zones is non-standard, so they are only meaningful in context of the original data set.